# Set a reminder for a user in #channel, selecting a different user alphabetically everyday at specified time

Tags: slack, slack-api

I have set up a channel in Slack with the purpose to remind a different user every day at 11:00 to do a specific task.

I know that by telling slack `/remind[who][when]["what"]` I can set reminders for a channel,
but Slack tells me *I’m sorry! Recurring reminders can’t be set for other members.*

I am wondering if there is an IFTTT/bot way of doing it so that I can rotate the 'who' alphabetically daily?

Any suggestion or pointer in the right direction is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the API method [`reminders.add`](https://api.slack.com/methods/reminders.add) to create reminders for users programmatically with a Slack bot.

Comment: So, I just made a POST call to https://slack.com/api/reminders.add with the token provided by the app/bot that now is integrated with #channel_that_should_shows_the_reminder  and when I set a user ID in the call (or none so it points the me, the user creating the request) 
Slackbot sends a private reminder

Comment: I don't get how I would set the reminder in such a way that the custom created bot/app reminds people in the public #channel_that_should_shows_the_reminder

Comment: yes. Apparently you can not specify a channel for the reminder to appear - it will always appear as direct message to the user.

Comment: So if you want your reminders to work differently I guess you best bet is to develop your own reminder bot.

Comment: It is if your bot calls the method with a user token.